# PHP mi script en sitios de terceros

Tags: php, javascript

Tengo el siguiente codigo php (simplificado) en mi-sitio.com/get-domain.php

```
<?php 
 $domain = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
 $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
 $sql = "INSERT INTO nombre-tabla (nombre-columna) VALUES ('$domain');
 $conn->close();
?>
```

Quiero que esto funcione en sitio-de-terceros.com/index.html de manera que se guarde en mi base de datos a traves de mi script los datos de quien visita sitio-de-terceros.com/index.html, en el supuesto que este otro sitio solo es en html entonces no puedo usar la funcion de include de php.

Entiendo que hay una forma usando javascript pero mi conocimiento es muy limitado y apenas estoy a prendiendo asi que les agradezco cualquier sugerencia especifica y detallada.

Comment: Vos queres inyectar esto en sitios que no son tuyos? como si fuera un virus? o un tracker?

Comment: ¿A qué llamas tú sitio de terceros? ¿Es una URL **de tu sitio** o es una URL de otro sitio que no está bajo tu dominio? La pregunta es muy confusa en ese punto.

Comment: @gbianchi, No, nada malicioso. Más bien como Google Analytics, que me proporciona un codigo y yo lo pongo en mi sitio web.
Por medio de este codigo (que es un javascript) Google puede monitorear el trafico de mi sitio y proporcionarme la informacion.

Comment: @A.Cedano, Es una URL de otro sitio que no esta bajo mi dominio. Imagina que el codigo php esta en mi servidor y quiero proporcionarte a ti la posibilidad de usar sus funciones, en tu sitio que esta en otro servidor. De forma transparente, sin hacks, solo porque yo tengo estas funciones en mi sistio y porque tu las quieres.

Comment: Eso es una API.. y vas a tener que epxoner la api de alguan forma...

Comment: Pues muy simple: agradecería tu generosidad y te diría que me pases los archivos que tienes un tu sitio, los agrego en mi sitio y todo el mundo feliz y nadie piensa mal de nadie. El escenario que dibujas sólo era posible antes del pecado original, ya no. Imagina que hay un hackeo en el sitio de terceros, ¿sabes del primero que van a sospechar? ¿sabes que a tu amigo que permitió que pusieras tu código en ese otro dominio lo podrían despedir? Como ves, hay muchos daños colaterales. Lo que quieres se puede hacer, pero violando seriamente la seguridad.